# How does the whatsapp chat history recovery work together with their encryption mechanism?

Tags: encryption, ios, rsa, whatsapp

As whatsapp states: every time user installs or updates the app, the new key pair would be generated on user's device. So I assume that, the chat history on icloud which was encrypted by the old public key should not be decrypted and readable.

But, what I found is that: users are still able to recover and read the chat history even they don't have the old private key(tested by changing to new device). So, how is this achieved by whatsapp? Private key never goes on network, and was not even stored on user's device anymore after updating the app or changing new device. How does the chat history recovery works then?

Answer (score 0):

Key pairs are used to cipher messages end to end, [here you can find more information](https://www.whatsapp.com/security/WhatsApp-Security-Whitepaper.pdf). The backup on the cloud (iCloud or GoogleDrive) or is done plain or also the keys are stored, there is no other way.

Comment: The backup records are confirm encrypted. But It shouldn't be together with the private key. If so, anyone who get the encrypted backup text can decrypt and get the plain text, even whatsapp stuffs.